# Do we have any substitute of "sforce.console.addEventListener" in Lightning Console Apis.

Tags: service-cloud-console

Please let me know if we can create any custom event in lightning like this. As of now they support few standard events but not sure if we have way to write custom events as well.

"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_events_lightning.htm"

Comment: If you are looking to write custom events in lightning, the yes you can do it. Is [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_events.htm) what you are looking for?

Comment: @JayantDas : No, you are referring lightning component events.  I was referring console toolkit events. like [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_addeventlistener.htm. So, My question is, Can we fire and listen events like this in new lightning console ?

Comment: @AbhishekRaj The console is still Lightning; you can use normal events to communicate between components.